# In what order is XMLHttpRequest() executed

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to figure out how to toggle the style display using plain javascript.

I have an XLMHttpRequest(). It works. The UI display is what I am working on. I would like the spin icon to show while the data is being loaded to the database. So, my code turns on the icon but the problem is when I add

```
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
```

to reset it to hidden. It never shows. So, here is my code.

```
    function runScript()
    {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'wenoconnected.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onprogress = function() {
           document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                if (this.responseText === 'imported') {
                        alert('Update Complete');
                    }
                 document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        xhr.send()
    }
```

I tried to have the page just reload after the alert is shown but all that does is immediately reloads the page without executing the xhr.send(). That is why I would like to know what order is the code executed. That way I will know where to place the display = "none".

Answer (score 1):

The latency is probably too low to notice the change (*which can be verified by simulating high latency on the server*). Try the following as an alternative:

**From:**

```
function runScript()
{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'wenoconnected.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onprogress = function() {
       document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            if (this.responseText === 'imported') {
                    alert('Update Complete');
                }
             document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    xhr.send()
}
```

**To:**

```
function runScript()
{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'wenoconnected.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            if (this.responseText === 'imported') {
                    alert('Update Complete');
                }
             document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
    xhr.send()
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- The `GET` request latency is slow enough that you'll see the indicator
- There is no other issue, related to CSS/HTML, that would prevent the indicator from showing
- Disregarding the obvious, like; whether the function is being executed, no typos for identifiers that’d prevent relevant code from executing, etc.